# Truth-neutral, truth-indifferent, & truth-committed verbs?

Tags: english, verbs, philosophy-of-language, logic, truth-value

In English,

> I go to the store.

is understood to mean

> It is true that I go to the store.

Suppose I want to succinctly express

> 1. I am indifferent to whether it is true or false that I go to the
>      store.

or

> 2. I do not know whether it is true or false that I go to the store.

How would one say this in English? Are there other languages whose verbs are truth-neutral or truth-indifferent instead of truth-committed as in English?

<sup>cf. this English Language Learners StackExchange question: "[Help pinpoint the usage of 'could' in these examples](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31342)."</sup>

Comment: That is called [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality).

Comment: @YellowSky Evidentiality requires a source of information, which neither of the examples seem to contain. I think these are cases of modality.

Comment: This is called modality (which subsumes evidentiality). Verbs in natural languages typically default to so-called positive modalities, other modalities need always be expressed periphrastically.